# Excepción al devolver una clase con un servicio WCF en C#: System.Net.WebException, Error al recibir la respuesta HTTP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, webservice, wcf

voy a explicar un poco mi problema.

Estoy desarrollando un servicio WCF en C# en visual studio 2017. Al servicio le envío un `byte[]` y este lo deserializa creando una clase con sus diferentes elementos (`string`, `int` y otras clases necesarias todos estos campos contenidos en esa clase). He comprobado que la deserializacion de ese `byte` xml se realiza con éxito, el problema viene cuando el servicio quiere devolverme esa clase.

Si intento devolver únicamente un campo `string` por ejemplo, lo devuelve con éxito. En cambio, si intento devolver la clase completa que necesito me devuelve la siguiente excepción:

> Excepción producida: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' en mscorlib.dll
>
> Excepcion: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal -2146233087
>   System.Net.WebException: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de recepción. ---> System.IO.IOException: No se puede
>   escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la
>   interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de
>   una conexión existente por el host remoto
>            en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>            en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>            --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
>            en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>            en System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>            en System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>            --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
>            en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>            en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>         Error al recibir la respuesta HTTP a http://localhost:52520/Service1.svc. Puede deberse a que el enlace del
>   extremo de servicio no usa el protocolo HTTP. También puede deberse a
>   que el servidor anula un contexto de solicitud HTTP (posiblemente por
>   el cierre del servicio). Consulte los registros del servidor para
>   obtener más información.
>         System.ServiceModel.Internals
>            en System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>            en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult
>   result)
>            en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
>            en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass7_01.b__0(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>            en System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, Task1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>         --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
>            en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>            en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>            en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
>            en WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.d__1.MoveNext()
>   en
>   D:\proyectosVS2017\servicio\Solution4\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:línea
>   43
>         TAsyncResult EndTAsyncResult

Creo... creo... que he escrito los diferentes `[DataContract]` en cada clase, y los diferentes `[DataMember]` en el interior de cada clase con cada elemento.

La forma con la que llamo al servicio es la siguiente, tras añadir el servicio como referencia, creo el cliente y llamo al método de forma asíncrona(b es el bytearray que quiero que deserialice el servicio), la excepción se da tras el return en el servicio.

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client cliente = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
var ejercicio = await cliente.getEjercicioDeserializadoAsync(b, t);
```

No se si puede ser un problema de permisos, de conexión, de excesivo tamaño de la clase a devolver o porque.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

he añadido la información del fichero web.config del servicio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeWeb"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxDepth="32"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca los valores siguientes en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Para recibir detalles de las excepciones en los fallos, con el fin de poder realizar la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Para no revelar información sobre las excepciones, establézcalo en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        Para examinar el directorio raíz de la aplicación web durante la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true.
        Establézcalo en false antes de la implementación para evitar revelar información sobre la carpeta de aplicación web.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

y este es el app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:52520/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

---

Te dejo como están ahora el web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeWeb"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxDepth="32"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca los valores siguientes en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Para recibir detalles de las excepciones en los fallos, con el fin de poder realizar la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Para no revelar información sobre las excepciones, establézcalo en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        Para examinar el directorio raíz de la aplicación web durante la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true.
        Establézcalo en false antes de la implementación para evitar revelar información sobre la carpeta de aplicación web.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

y el app.config

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Graph">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"   maxBufferSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:52520/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

creo haber añadido las cosas que me has ido comentando, pero a pesar de ello la

> excepción resultante creo que es la misma
>
> Excepción producida: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' en
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Excepcion: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>
> -2146233087 System.Net.WebException: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de recepción. ---> System.IO.IOException: No se puede
>   escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la
>   interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de
>   una conexión existente por el host remoto    en
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    en
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---    en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   en System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    en
>   System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    ---
>   Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---    en
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result) Error al recibir la respuesta HTTP a
>   http://localhost:52520/Service1.svc. Puede deberse a que el enlace del
>   extremo de servicio no usa el protocolo HTTP. También puede deberse a
>   que el servidor anula un contexto de solicitud HTTP (posiblemente por
>   el cierre del servicio). Consulte los registros del servidor para
>   obtener más información. System.ServiceModel.Internals    en
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>
>   en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult
>   result)    en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action,
>   Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)    en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.b__0(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    en
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---    en
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    en
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   en
>   WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.d__1.MoveNext()
>   en
>   D:\proyectosVS2017\servicio\Solution4\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:línea
>   43 TAsyncResult EndTAsyncResult

Comment: Estaría bien saber el tamaño en bytes que devuelves. Quizás sea demasiado grande, de ahí que corta la conexión. Para ello prueba a serializar la  clase y grabarla en un fichero. Si tiene un tamaño muy grande quizás tengas que cambiar alguna configuración para poder devolver más información. Piensa que serializar una clase a XML hace que "engorde" mucho :)

Comment: Pon en el post la configuración bindings que hay en system.serviceModel. Qiuzás haciendo más grande el maxBufferPoolSize,maxBufferSize y maxReceivedMessageSize se solucione.

Comment: pues el xml es bastante grande la verdad, depende el bytearray, pero en general suelen rondar las 1000 lineas de xml, y si lo guardo en un fichero, por ejemplo con el que probe, 50KB de fichero de texto xml

Comment: Tarda mucho en generarse el XML? porque entonces puede ser por el TimeOut del binding.

Comment: Pues la deserializacion del xml en el ordenador tarda unos 2-3 segundos. Depende el xml pero más o menos eso tarda. He añadido la configuración del web.config por si sirve de algo

Comment: El web.config de proyecto WCF lo puedes poner?

Comment: Esta añadido arriba en mi pregunta

Comment: Marcos, disculpa si me equivoco. Esa configuracionde Web.Config parece más de la aplicación Cliente que del propio servicio WCF. El Servicio WCF tiene su propio web.Config y ahí también hay que añadir algunas cosas para transmitir ficheros algo más grandes. De todos modos 50k me parece poco para que falle...

Comment: Tenias toda la razón, había añadido el app.config y no el web.config, ya están ambos arriba, a ver si hay suerte

Comment: @MarcosMuñozMorales Hola Marcos, agrega información [editando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/142444/edit) tu respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a ir por partes. Después de todos los comentarios:
Parece que el problema **no está en el Servicio WCF puesto que como me dices ahí se serializa perfectamente** e incluso eres capaz de guardar el XML Serializado.

Tampoco puede ser error de la **clase puesto que llegas a serializarla en el XML** antes mencionado.
Por lo tanto vamos a dejar el web.Config de la App cliente así:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="Graph">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000"/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"   maxBufferSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:50792/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="BasicHttpBinding.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: lo pongo tal cual y el problema se mantiene, como puedo definir esos bindings del servicio? por probar a ver si es eso.

Comment: No devuelvo un xml, le envío al servicio un xml en formato de bytearray, y este lo deserializa y me devuelve la clase, lo único que esta clase que devuelvo tiene muchos elementos

Comment: Has añadido dentro de behavior   <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>

Comment: sisisis, tal cual

Comment: Voy a intentar ponerte la configuración de EndPoint. Quizás así funcione.

Comment: Si sirve de algo, la excepción salta tras el return en el servidor, si lo depuro paso a paso, deserializa perfecto, pero en el momento de devolver la clase. Lo que comentaba, si devuelvo un solo elemento por ejemplo un elemento que es de tipo string todo va bien, pero si devuelvo la clase completa, o un elemento que tenga otros dentro, salta la excepcion en el lado del cliente.  Te he actualizado mi webconfig con ese maxItemsInObjectGraph

Comment: Hay que añadir tambíen el behavior del endPoint en el web.Config de la aplicación. Te lo puse en lo Editado arriba.

Comment: No se si encima o debajo de esta respuesta e añadido el estado de los config tanto del app.config como del web.config con los nuevos cambios, sin exito. Puede que no se pueda enviar esa clase a través del servicio?

Comment: Edite mi respuesta. Deja el web.Config de la App como te pongo arriba. El problema parece que está ahí y no en el Config del WCF.

Comment: Editado y puesto como me dices, mismo error que desde que comenzamos, espero no haberla liado en algún parámetro de configuración mientras. Únicamente cambia el puerto, que he mantenido el que llevo desde que cree el servicio.

Comment: ¿puedes poner una parte o el XML que serializa en tu pregunta inicial? Tampoco estaría tener la clase. Otra cosa que puedes probar es testear el Servicio WCF con SoapUI por ejemplo para ir descartando cosas.

Comment: La clase seria esta  https://gist.github.com/markiteps/8dbb5d1bd4d3b7d79e295861d61da391    , la cual se crea de forma correcta en el servidor tras deserializar y este seria el metodo del servicio  https://gist.github.com/markiteps/44f7dcf8b2e4352a0232dfa47fa0791c   si en lugar de devolver un elemento, devuelvo un string de cualquier campo de la clase, obtengo el string en el destino a ver si hay suerte y es algo de la clase

Comment: ¿Has hecho debug del WCF cuando le llega la petición del cliente? Es decir, el WCF llega a serializar pero falla en el cliente.

Comment: He ido linea a linea pulsando F10 para la depuracion, y cuando llega al return y paso a la siguiente linea, salta la excepcion. Es el momento en el que tendria que pasar al cliente ya que deberia de recibir los datos. En el cliente el código es simple ya que solo tengo esas dos lineas, la creacion del cliente y la llamada al metodo: 
                                   ServiceReference1.Service1Client cliente = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
                
                var ejercicio = await cliente.getEjercicioDeserializadoAsync(b, t);

Comment: Osea que mandas bytes que luego conviertes en XML (si es un XML). Es decir ,es un Sevicio que convierte bytes enviados en un XML. En este caso asegurate de que llegan por completo todos los bytes. ¿De cuanto tamaño estamos hablando? el que envías. Por otro lado, ejercicio1.ejercicioDes.Pantallas.Pantalla[1].Elementos.Elemento[1] existe? es decir, no es un objeto que sea nulo?

Comment: Envío bytes que convierto en xml, y ese xml lo deserializo para crear la clase y por ultimo, devuelvo la clase creada al cliente. Esta clase tiene elementos algunos elementos nulos que no se utilizan después, pero eso no afecta no? o es que no pueden enviarse elementos nulos?  El byte[] que envío al servidor quizás tenga unos 40.000 bytes de longitud, pero el servidor los recibe todos, si no no deserializaria.

Comment: Si puedes pon en github el XML serializado. Una cosa que no entiendo que, si usas dataContracts, puedes hacer la llamada de otra manera al servicio WCF. En vez de var ejercicio = await cliente.getEjercicioDeserializadoAsync(b, t);  podrías poner directamente que tipo de objeto es, es decir, element.

Comment: No entiendo, la clase del xml o te refieres al xml en texto claro?